# How to log 500 internal server errors

Tags: c#, iis-6, asmx, asp.net-3.5, internal-server-error

One of my web pages is giving me an:

```
GET url_plus_query_string_go_here 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

type of error.  How do I set the page/server up so I can log these errors to find out more about them and why they are happening?

Comment: Look at the event viewer to see what's went on.

Comment: This question may get better response on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RowlandShaw: I disagree. This is specific to the technology stack being used, in this case ASP.NET

Comment: @DanielHilgarth I'd see this more as a question about configuring the webserver, and where the logs are; sure, there are options on telemetry in the code, to improve the quality of what is logged, etc. but you still need to know how to read the logs.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: My suggestion using ELMAH is specific to ASP.NET. It is independent of the web-server being used.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth the question is tagged as IIS6, which would be set up to log errors automatically, so believe it's just a case of knowing where to look.

Comment: @RowlandShaw: It's additionally tagged ASP.NET. I guess we have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @DarrenDavies, just had a look and no entries were made with todays date, even though the error has happened many times today.

Comment: I'm not using ASP.NET MVC, So can you please provide an `This question already has an answer here`, which shows how to do this using IIS6, .NET 3.5, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to easily log all exceptions.

It adds a message handler to your ASP.NET application that automatically logs your exceptions to a database and provides a web interface to view them.

Aside from setting up the database and adjusting your web.config you don't have to change anything in your application. Especially, you don't have to add try catch handlers to all your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class Log.cs and use write a method to log the exception into a text file.
Now call this method in your code (e.g. in catch block). Use following code to create a class log.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace TestApp
{
public class Log
{
    protected static string GetFileName()
    {
        return "log.txt";
    }

    public Log()
    {

    }

    public static void Write(string message)
    {
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(GetFullFilePath(), message + Environment.NewLine);
    }



    public static string ReadAll()
    {
        return System.IO.File.ReadAllText(GetFullFilePath());
    }

    private static string GetFullFilePath()
    {
        return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, GetFileName());
    }
}
}
```

Now apply following code to insert your exception or anything else which you want to track on run time. I show only catch block here but you can use it anywhere in your code.

```
    catch (Exception ex)
        {
          Log.Write(DateTime.Now + "  " + ex.Message + "  Something relevant string");
        }
```

Comment: This gives me an error message: `The name 'path' does not exist in the current context.`.

Comment: Add Name Space System.IO i.e. using System.IO